# Changing window title in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there a way to change the window title of my SQL Server Management Studio to display current server I'm connected to?

To know which DB I'm connected to, I have to scroll all the way up to see the name of the server and it's a pain..

Maybe there's an available plug-in or something.

Comment: We have a similar question : [SQL Server Management Studio, getting title bar to show more detail.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174111/sql-server-management-studio-getting-title-bar-to-show-more-detail)
You can connect to multiple servers at a time so displaying server names will be an issue? :)

Comment: SQL Server **2008** Management Studio can do this out of the box - you can define a color (not for the title, but for the status bar of your query window) on a per-connection basis. And you can connect to SQL Server 2000 and 2005 databases with SSMS 2008, too, no problem.

Comment: Tried that for a couple of months. Noticed I don't really pay attention to the bottom line...

Comment: Exact solution of your problem ist described in [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10319877/1249405). You will have to install free add-in for ssms to achieve it.

Comment: SSMS Boost (http://www.ssmsboost.com) will allow you to modify the window title of SSMS. I'm using it now and have had no problems with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SSMSTools](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) will colour code each management studio window based on the server you're using. It's a start and it's free.

Comment: Looks like it's not free anymore, [SSMSBoost](https://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-window-title) has a free version. Needs to be activated but it is free. I haven't checked it out but I'm about to.